# Arraylist is returning null in asynchronous method?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I am facing the problem in JSON data from server is saved in the ArrayList is returning null when the ArrayList is called in the custom adapter. The custom adapter is used to list the data in the spinner in android.

```
public class PhotoCommnFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
EditText rechargeMobileNumber,rechargeAmount;
Spinner selectMenu;
int flags[] = {R.drawable.airteltv, R.drawable.aircel, R.drawable.dishtv, R.drawable.sundirect, R.drawable.tatasky, R.drawable.videocon};
List<SpinnerMenu> selectedNetwork = new ArrayList<>();
public PhotoCommnFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_mobile, container, false);
    mobileRecahrgeHistory();
    rechargeMobileNumber = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recharge_mobile_number);
    rechargeAmount = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recharge_amount);
    selectMenu = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.selectNetwork);
    settingSpinnerDropDown();
    return rootView;
}

public void mobileRecahrgeHistory(){
    Ion.with(this)
            .load("http://192.168.1.105/TotalRecharge/?api=ol&uid=1")
            .asJsonObject().withResponse()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> result) {
                    JSONObject json = null;

                    try {
                        json = new JSONObject(result.getResult().toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // Create the root JSONObject from the JSON string.
                    JSONObject jsonRootObject = null;
                    jsonRootObject = json.optJSONObject("DS");

                    //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("LST");

                    //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
                    for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                        try {
                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String iph = null;

                        String oid = jsonObject.optString("OID").toString();
                        String ocd = jsonObject.optString("OCD").toString();
                        String opd = jsonObject.optString("OPE").toString();
                        String mil = jsonObject.optString("MIL").toString();
                        String mxl = jsonObject.optString("MXL").toString();
                        try {
                             iph = jsonObject.getString("IPH").toString();
                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        String urldisplay = "http://192.168.1.105/TotalRecharge/"+iph;
                        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                        try {
                            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                        } catch (Exception e3) {
                            e3.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        SpinnerMenu spinnerData = new SpinnerMenu();
                        spinnerData.setOid(oid);
                        spinnerData.setOcd(ocd);
                        spinnerData.setOpd(opd);
                        spinnerData.setMil(mil);
                        spinnerData.setMix(mxl);
                        spinnerData.setImage(mIcon11);

                        selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData);

                    }

                }

            });
}


public void settingSpinnerDropDown(){
    Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter customAdapter=new Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_dth_main_spinner_items,R.id.serviceName,selectedNetwork);
    selectMenu.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}
```

in the aove method the data from internet are saved in arraylist but when the arraylist is called in Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter` the arraylist is returning null. I checked by debugging the datas are save in arraylist.
I refferred in stackoverflow that you should add the

Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in your method. I don't know where to add this method . In my method the the asynchronous method called  before calling the custom adapter . Then what is the use of using this method. Please help me.

The below code is Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter  adapter class

```
 public class Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpinnerMenu> {
        Context context;
    int flags[];
    List<SpinnerMenu> countryNames;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter(FragmentActivity activity, int resouceId, int textviewId, List<SpinnerMenu> data) {


   //     super(activity, R.layout.fragment_dth_main_spinner_items,userstories);
        super(activity,resouceId,textviewId,data);
        this.countryNames = data;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView names;
        ImageView icon;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater  = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dth_main_spinner_items, parent, false);
   //     convertView = inflter.inflate(fragment_dth_main_spinner_items, null);
        SpinnerMenu spinnerData = countryNames.get(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        View result;

        if(convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
             viewHolder.names = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serviceName);
            result = convertView;
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }
//        viewHolder.icon.setImageBitmap(spinnerData.getImage());
//        Glide.with(context).load(spinnerData.getImages()).into(viewHolder.icon);
        viewHolder.names.setText(spinnerData.getOpd());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your customadapter global and call notifydatasetchanged in oncomplete

```
public class PhotoCommnFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    EditText rechargeMobileNumber, rechargeAmount;
    Spinner selectMenu;
    int flags[] = {R.drawable.airteltv, R.drawable.aircel, R.drawable.dishtv, R.drawable.sundirect, R.drawable.tatasky, R.drawable.videocon};
    List<SpinnerMenu> selectedNetwork = new ArrayList<>();
    Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter customAdapter;

    public PhotoCommnFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_mobile, container, false);
        mobileRecahrgeHistory();
        rechargeMobileNumber = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recharge_mobile_number);
        rechargeAmount = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recharge_amount);
        selectMenu = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.selectNetwork);
        settingSpinnerDropDown();
        customAdapter = new Fragment_DTH_Main_Spinner_Adapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_dth_main_spinner_items, R.id.serviceName, selectedNetwork);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void mobileRecahrgeHistory() {
        Ion.with(this)
                .load("http://192.168.1.105/TotalRecharge/?api=ol&uid=1")
                .asJsonObject().withResponse()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> result) {
                        JSONObject json = null;

                        try {
                            json = new JSONObject(result.getResult().toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // Create the root JSONObject from the JSON string.
                        JSONObject jsonRootObject = null;
                        jsonRootObject = json.optJSONObject("DS");

                        //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("LST");

                        //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                            try {
                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String iph = null;

                            String oid = jsonObject.optString("OID").toString();
                            String ocd = jsonObject.optString("OCD").toString();
                            String opd = jsonObject.optString("OPE").toString();
                            String mil = jsonObject.optString("MIL").toString();
                            String mxl = jsonObject.optString("MXL").toString();
                            try {
                                iph = jsonObject.getString("IPH").toString();
                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            String urldisplay = "http://192.168.1.105/TotalRecharge/" + iph;
                            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                            try {
                                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                            } catch (Exception e3) {
                                e3.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            SpinnerMenu spinnerData = new SpinnerMenu();
                            spinnerData.setOid(oid);
                            spinnerData.setOcd(ocd);
                            spinnerData.setOpd(opd);
                            spinnerData.setMil(mil);
                            spinnerData.setMix(mxl);
                            spinnerData.setImage(mIcon11);

                            selectedNetwork.add(spinnerData);
                            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }

                    }

                });
    }


    public void settingSpinnerDropDown() {

        selectMenu.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: the custom  adapter is initialized after the asynchronous method but adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is called inside the asynchronous method. Will this cause the null pointer exception

Comment: This will/should not cause Null Pointer. Please try it

Comment: Still the issue is not solved ,its returning null values